# Angels Eating: The case of Avraham Vs Lot

Tags: malach-angel, abraham, vayera

I came across a fascinating [Tanna D'Vei Eliyahu Rabbah (12:1)](https://www.sefaria.org/Tanna_Debei_Eliyahu_Rabbah.12.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) which states:

> וכל האומר לא אכלו מלאכי השרת עם אברהם אע"ה לא אמר כלום אלא בצדקתו של אותו צדיק ובשכר טורח שטרח בשבילם פתח להם הקב"ה את פיהם ואכלו ולכך נאמר והוא עומד עליהם תחת העץ ויאכלו
>
> *And all who say that the ministering angels did not eat with Avraham is talking nonsense (lit. nothingness), rather due to the righteousness of the Tzaddik (i.e. Avraham) and the reward for all the effort/bother he expended, Hashem opened their mouths and they ate. Therefore it says, "And he stood over them under the tree and they ate."*

So it would seem that ordinarily angels do not eat and it was only because of the fact that they were in a tzaddik's presence, that Hashem made them eat.

This all makes perfect sense....

However, when we get to the episode with Lot and his hosting of the malachim, the pasuk in [Bereishis 19:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.19.3?lang=bi&aliyot=0) writes:

> וַיִּפְצַר־בָּ֣ם מְאֹ֔ד וַיָּסֻ֣רוּ אֵלָ֔יו וַיָּבֹ֖אוּ אֶל־בֵּית֑וֹ וַיַּ֤עַשׂ לָהֶם֙ מִשְׁתֶּ֔ה וּמַצּ֥וֹת אָפָ֖ה **וַיֹּאכֵֽלוּ**׃
>
> *But he urged them strongly, so they turned his way and entered his house. He prepared a feast for them and baked unleavened bread, **and they ate**.*

So how come in this instance they ate? Lot was not exactly a tzaddik<sup>1</sup> - How come with him they ate too?

I haven't seen any sources that say that they didn't really eat. In fact, [Rabbeinu Bachya](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.19.3?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rabbeinu_Bahya%2C_Bereshit.19.3.1&lang2=bi) and the [Ohr HaChaim](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.19.3?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Or_HaChaim_on_Genesis.19.3.1&lang2=bi) both contrast their eating with Lot and Avraham by noting how they specifically ate bread/matzos by Lot as opposed to meat like in the case of Avraham - but they still ate?!

---

<sup>1 Refer to [Bereishis Rabbah 41:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.41.7?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) which interprets the words "וַיִּשָֹּׂא לוֹט אֶת עֵינָיו וַיַּרְא אֶת כָּל כִּכַּר הַיַּרְדֵּן" - "And Lot lifted up his eyes and he saw the entire plain of the Jordan" ([Bereishis 13:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.13.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) as a reference to immorality, and that he settled there despite looking at many other cities as he found it the most attractive option. Or, alternatively note the [Midrash Tanchuma Buber Edition - Vayeira 21:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma_Buber%2C_Vayera.21.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that says out of the five jusdges in Sodom, Lot was the most wicked.</sup>

Comment: Maybe they were really hungry by the time they reached Sodom. Long walk, you know... ;) Actually, it occurs to me now that maybe that act of Hashem opening their mouths to eat somehow kept them in a state of being more physical until their mission was over (post destruction of Sodom).

Comment: I hear - but why would Hashem need to 'give' them food to make them more 'physical'?

Comment: Maybe it's not a need but a consequence? The first eating was "needed" to respect Avraham. The ensuing physicality was a consequence?

Comment: I would assume the default is they didn't really eat. This midrash is innovating by Avraham that they really are. I don't see why that carries over to Lot

Comment: Thanks @Robev - Possibly the beginnings of an answer by the Radak - https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.19.3?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Radak_on_Genesis.19.3.3&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en

Comment: Maybe Lot had (via his time with Avraham, and only in this dimension of being) risen to a level of Tzadik, espeically in his willingness to טורח שטרח even in a place like S'dom.

Comment: @interested I mentioned the Ohr HaChaim - my point is that they still ate...

Comment: I added the medrash tanchuma which connects the malachim eating at both Avraham and Lot with Moshe not eating for forty days and nights when he went up to get the luchos

Comment: I remember a shiur it which Lot caused the destruction of S'dom because he was an honest judge and enforced the laws as they were written. The other judges accepted bribes to let people off so the accused were not killed. The medrash tanchuma does not say he was the most wicked, but that he was the least in stature (had just been appointed so was most junior).

Comment: May I point out that the hebrew word for angels actually refers to messengers. I know that we often refer to them as heavenly beings of some kind, but a malach can be any messenger even human kinds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is a contrast to Avraham, whose whole family took part, Rav Hirsch points out that Lot did behave as he had learned from Avraham.

> Even in his own house he stands alone with that he had learnt from Abraham.

However the fact that he rose above everyone else does show a merit on his part. Indeed, his daughters thought that everyone else in the world had died (like Noach). [Vayeira 20:31](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8214/jewish/Chapter-19.htm/showrashi/true#v31)

[Medrash Tanchuma](https://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Bereshit/19.3#e0n6) asks that question.

> וּמַצּוֹת אָפָה וַיֹּאכֵלוּ – וַהֲלֹא אֵין אֲכִילָה לְמַלְאֲכֵי
> הַשָּׁרֵת. אֶלָּא לְלַמֶּדְךָ דֶּרֶךְ אֶרֶץ, שֶׁלֹּא יְשַׁנֶּה אָדָם
> מִמִּנְהַג הַמְּדִינָה. אַתָּה לָמֵד מִמֹּשֶׁה, שֶׁהֲרֵי מֹשֶׁה
> שֶׁעָלָה לַמָּרוֹם כְּתִיב בּוֹ, וַיְהִי שָׁם עִם י״י אַרְבָּעִים יוֹם
> וְאַרְבָּעִים לַיְלָה לֶחֶם לֹא אָכַל וּמַיִם לֹא שָׁתָה (שמות
> ל״ד:כ״ח). אִלְמָלֵי הָיָה שָׁם אֲכִילָה וּשְׁתִיָּה, הָיָה אוֹכֵל
> וְשׁוֹתֶה, הַמַּלְאָכִים שֶׁבָּאוּ לְבַקֵּר אֶת אַבְרָהָם וְשֶׁבָּאוּ
> לְשַׁחֵת אֶת סְדוֹם וּלְהַצִּיל אֶת לוֹט, כְּתִיב בָּהֶן וַיַּעַשׂ
> לָהֶם מִשְׁתֶּה וּמַצּוֹת אָפָה וַיֹּאכֵלוּ.
>
> The *malachei hashareis* do not eat. However this teaches that a
> *person* should not change the custom of a location. Moshe went to the heavens and it is written there, *He was there with the Lord for forty
> days and forty nights; he ate no bread and drank no water.* ([Shmos
> 34:28](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9895/showrashi/true#v28))
> Since this was a place where one eats and drinks, they would eat and
> drink, The *malachim* that came to visit Avraham and to destroy S'dom
> and to save Lot, it is written *and he made them a feast, and he baked
> unleavened cakes, and they ate.*

Or Hachaim says that they only ate the matzos while with Avraham they also ate the meat which was the equivalent of a korbon for Hashem because Lot did not keep the Torah like Avraham.

**Rashi**

> **and there is no man on earth:** They thought that the entire world had been
> destroyed, as in the Generation of the Flood (Gen. Rabbah 51:8).

Answer (score 1):

Harav Yaakov Chaim Goldwicht ztsl (אסופת מערכת פרשת וירא) has a long essay in which he explains the power of a person's holy thoughts as he is doing an act. Just like the thoughts of the one who spins wool for the sake of tzitzis, "elevates" the threads in a way that they may now no longer be used for ordinary uses, and like preparing the hide of an animal for the sake of a Sefer Torah "elevates" ordinary skin into קלף with its inherent קדושת ספר תורה, so too the thoughts of Abraham and Sarah into the kneading of the dough and the preparation of the food, elevated the food into a "spiritual food" not unlike the מן, which the angels could actually eat.
But that indeed does not explain how a person like לוט, despite his "greatness" whilst living in סדום as mentioned earlier, could cook food with the same lofty thoughts.

Comment: Interesting! Thank you